# OnDisconnet() method not working

Tags: atmosphere

In Atmosphere Framework `onDisconnect()` method is not working for me if Network cable is connected, but when I close the browser it's working.

What is the solution to solve this?

**This is my code:**

```
public void onDisconnect(AtmosphereResourceEvent event) 
{
     logger.trace("", event);
     if (event.isCancelled()) {
        when request.enableProtocol
     } else if (event.isClosedByClient()) {

     }
}
```